# C# Controls only appear after application.doevent is called

Tags: c#

I had a problem yesterday that bothered me for hours. At some point in my program, another thread changes the controls on a form (for example visibility and loading images). No exceptions are thrown (`checkforillegalcrossthread...=false`). However, the changes do not apply until `application.doevent()` is called. If that isn't enough, the Application hangs if `application.doevent()` isn't called!

My first guess (and yours probably too) was that the UI thread (main thread) is busy, but it isn't. It does not have any code to run, it does not run anything during debugging and it's just stuck on the `Application.run(..)` line, however it is the thread that created the controls.

Any ideas what the problem is?

After reading the answers, I'd rather reformulate my question. How can I know if my main thread is indeed idle? What I normally do is pause all other threads during debugging, change to my main thread and see the next instruction. If nothing happens when I move a step, then it is idle. Is there any other way?

Comment: please, please don't set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to false.  You're only opening yourself up for a world of hurt.

Comment: If the application is hanging then chances are your UI thread is being blocked.  It doesn't sound like your debugging technique to determine what the UI is doing is as sound as you seem to think.  My guess is it is being blocked somewhere.  (If it was being blocked somewhere else `Application.Run` would still be in it's call stack, so the debugger telling you that it's executing that method isn't wrong, but it's not really helpful information either.)

Comment: I've heard this a lot about not using `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`but why? It's just an exception telling two threads are working on the same data structure and there is a possibility that the program acts undeterministic. Big Deal, any other data structure would have the same issue. Using Invoke does not make your program deterministic, so you might as well just set it to false.

Comment: The problem is that the controls aren't self contained. They're not only using state that's specific to that control. Each control is likely to be manipulating state that's at the scope of the entire application. You can't just make sure that you aren't manipulating that one control between multiple threads, you need to make sure that you're never manipulating *any* UI controls from multiple threads, at which point there's no productivity to be gained from using multiple threads (the work is still serialized) so you may as well force it to one thread  Not doing so adds risk with no benefit.

Comment: What is State? What does "each control is likely to be manipulating state that's at the scope of the entire application" mean?

Comment: state is any information that is stored, i.e. variables.  Setting the text of a label doesn't just manipulate that label.  It can also make that label larger, which ends up pushing some other control further over, changing it's location, possibly even making it larger/smaller, which could determine what fits on the screen, which determine's what's rendered, which determine which events can be fired/processed, etc. Everything is tightly intertwined.  In non-UI related multithreaded code the objects are (hopefully) not so interconnected; you can manipulate one with no visible effects on another.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by trying to change the controls from a different thread.

You can correct it by using [`Control.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) or [`Control.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to run the code that updates the control.

For example, this `SetLabel()` method is safe to be called from a separate thread. It checks [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) to see if this is being called from a thread other than the UI thread. If it is, it uses `BeginInvoke()` to pass a delegate to the UI thread for execution.

The delegate is in the form of a lambda expression, `() => label1.Text = text`, which simply sets the label's text. It has to be wrapped in an [`Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate for use with `BeginInvoke()`.

```
public void SetLabel(string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = text));
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

It is usually better to use `BeginInvoke()` rather than `Invoke()` *where possible* because it greatly reduces the chance of deadlock.

For an interesting discussion about this, see [this blog](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/a-concrete-example-of-how-control-invoke-can-cause-deadlock/).

Comment: Interestingly, I used Invoke in a later part of the program to again change the controls. However, it fails! Only BeginInvoke worked. But why should Invoking be necessarily at all? I did not use invoke in the past and everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: It depends on the control; some do work when called from another thread, others work only intermittently, and others don't work at all.

Comment: I also noticed that when using only invoke, the program hangs at the line this.Invoke(...). No exceptions, nothing. It looks as if it is waiting for the main thread, but the main thread is definitely idle.

Comment: I've encountered many cases where Invoke() doesn't work. It's extremely easy to get deadlocked with Invoke(), and for that reason I use BeginInvoke() where possible.

Comment: Do you have any reference to back that up? Or can you say why it is so?

Comment: Yes, it's because when you call Invoke(), the caller waits for the UI to respond. If the UI tries to do anything that ends up waiting for the Invoker(), it deadlocks. [Here's an example](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/a-concrete-example-of-how-control-invoke-can-cause-deadlock/)

Comment: No I meant back this up: "some do work when called from another thread, others work only intermittently, and others don't work at all.".

Comment: Oh I see - well, just what I have observed when experimenting some time ago. Labels did seem to work fine, but a table control I was trying definitely went wrong. But if you read microsoft's documentation for [CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx), it does say *When a thread other than the creating thread of a control tries to access one of that control's methods or properties, it often leads to unpredictable results*, which is something I have personally observed.